# Differences between RepeatedStratifiedKFold and StratifiedKFold in sklearn

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, classification, cross-validation

I tried to read the docs for [`RepeatedStratifiedKFold`](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.RepeatedStratifiedKFold.html) and [`StratifiedKFold`](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.StratifiedKFold.html), but couldn't tell the difference between the two methods except that `RepeatedStratifiedKFold` repeats `StratifiedKFold`  ***n* times** with different randomization in each repetition.

My question is: Do these two methods return the same results? Which one should I use to split an **imbalanced** dataset when doing `GridSearchCV` and what is the rationale for choosing that method?

Answer (score 11):

Both [`StratifiedKFold`](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.StratifiedKFold.html) and [`RepeatedStratifiedKFold`](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.RepeatedStratifiedKFold.html) can be very effective when used on classification problems with a severe class imbalance. They both *stratify* the sampling by the class label; that is, they split the dataset in such a way that preserves approximately the same class distribution (i.e., the same percentage of samples of each class) in each subset/fold as in the original dataset. However, a single run of `StratifiedKFold` might result in a noisy estimate of the model's performance, as different splits of the data might result in very different results. That is where `RepeatedStratifiedKFold` comes into play.

`RepeatedStratifiedKFold` allows improving the estimated performance of a machine learning model, by simply repeating the [cross-validation](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/cross_validation.html) procedure multiple times (according to the `n_repeats` value), and reporting the *mean* result across all folds from all runs. This *mean* result is expected to be a more accurate estimate of the model's performance (see [this article](https://machinelearningmastery.com/repeated-k-fold-cross-validation-with-python/)).

Thus—to answer your question—**no**, these two methods would **not** provide the same results. Using `RepeatedStratifiedKFold` means that each time running the procedure would result in a different split of the dataset into stratified *k*-folds, and hence, the performance results would be different.

`RepeatedStratifiedKFold` has the benefit of improving the estimated model's performance at the cost of fitting and evaluating many more models. If, for example, 5 repeats (i.e., `n_repeats=5`) of 10-fold cross-validation were used for estimating the model's performance, it means that 50 different models would need to be fitted (trained) and evaluated—which might be computationally expensive, depending on the dataset's size, type of machine learning algorithm, device specifications, etc. However,  `RepeatedStratifiedKFold` process could be executed on different cores or different machines, which could dramatically speed up the process. For instance, setting `n_jobs=-1` would use all the cores available on your system (have a look [here](https://machinelearningmastery.com/multi-core-machine-learning-in-python/)).

When it comes to evaluation, make sure to use appropriate metrics, as described in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70850584/17865804).

Comment: Thanks Chris. But if we set the the argument `shuffle=True` in `StratifiedKFold` that might reduce the chance of *noisy estimate of model* as per your reply. Moreover,  `GridSearchCV(estimator(200), cv=StratifiedKFold)` might be as *comprehensive* as `GridSearchCV(estimator(100), cv=RepeatedStratifiedKFold)` as it has twice as iterations/epochs?